# I need help with Fourier Series

Tags: signal, homework, fourier, system

[image]

I am having problems analyzing this sketch of a continuous Fourier series as it can't find a single known function

Comment: That isn't a sketch of a continuous Fourier series. You need to show some effort when it comes to homework. This isn't a free homework service. Get you finger out and do some math.

Answer (score 0):

You need to integrate the function over one period with the Fourier basis functions, \$cos(\frac{2\pi nt}{T})\$ and \$sin(\frac{2\pi nt}{T})\$. If you are clever about using the symmetries a little, you can reduce the work you have to do.